# .net core date format on Linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, .net-core

I'm migrating my code from .net framework to .net core and testing it on a Linux machine, one of the issues I had a problem with is the date format when calling DateTime ToString() function, in Windows the default date format is guided by the OS and can be customized in the settings I've tried to do something similar in Linux by defining a new locale file with the wanted format and setting up the proper variable (LC_Time). When asking the system for the date I get an answer in the wanted format but when running the code I still get "wrong" one. Am I missing something?

Comment: To make things more simple the format is MM/dd/yyyy and I'm trying to change it to dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: What if you will try to specify locale directly in ToString() call?

Comment: Regarding dd/MM/yyyy use "en-GB" instead of "en-US". That is not clear from your original question.

Comment: Calling ToString(dd/MM/yyyy) works but unfortunately not a solution in my case

Comment: Although I did not try "en-GB" or any other pre-made locale, I did copy "en-US" file changed the d_fmt and changed the environment variable to reference it. Now I know it worked since the format did changed in the system (for example when asking for the date)

Comment: Use CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(string name) method to get any appropriate culture (en-GB or your custom one) and pass date time format of culture to ToString call.

Comment: Like I said, what you are suggesting will work but it's not the solution I'm looking for, assume I don't have access to the code. I know the code calls for DateTime ToString() and I can't change it.

Comment: Does setting `Thread.CurrentCulture` to a different culture work? If really necessary you could even create your own culture.

Comment: @CodesInChaos if there is a way to set the CurrentCulture on a process level it might work. Changing it on a Thread level leaves me open to cases when API I'm using starts it's own thread.

Comment: But I'm sure this can be fixed on an OS level it's either that or .net-core doesn't use locale environment variable as default culture the same as Windows

Comment: New threads should get their locale from `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture`

Comment: @CodesInChaos looks promising, if I set this property at the start of my program every thread  will have the proper CultureInfo, will try it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question, but I just had that issue. It's a ["bug / feature / expected behavior"](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/11221) of .NET Core 2...

> This is happening because the default short date for en-US (on Linux) is M/d/yy. the way determine the default short date is the code
>
> https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/corefx/System.Globalization.Native/calendarData.cpp#L527
>
> https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/corefx/System.Globalization.Native/calendarData.cpp#L281
>
> the default short date pattern used is the first one returned from this enumeration and it looks that what ICU return for KShort

**But**, it will change/be fixed in .NET Core 3 according to this [pull request](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/18316):

> > I tried to use dotnet core build pack 2.1.3, it did not resolve my issue (still getting 7/6/18) for format d, could you please help me to resolve for the same. Thanks in advance
>
> This is fixed in 3.0. we didn't change 2.1 behavior for app compatibility reason.